# Generate report with maven plugin

Tags: maven-plugin

I am creating a maven plugin for 2.1 to executed fitnesse test on remote server(existing fitnesse plugin is not working for me). Can you please let me know how can we generate report like unit test case report is generated ?
Can you also please let me know that how can  I  the build as soon as the error is encountered ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would like to take a look at [this plugin I wrote during 2012](http://code.google.com/p/fitnesse-launcher-maven-plugin/)?

Both the reporting and failing of the build is handled by the `VerifyMojo`, using `org.apache.maven.surefire.failsafe.model.FailsafeSummary` generated by the `RunTestsMojo`.